# Dragon's Dogma Dark Arisen german to english language

Tags: ps3, dragons-dogma

I have a doubt regarding the German version of Dark Arisen.
I'm interested in buying it here, for PS3, in Germany, but I am afraid it comes only with German Language.

I know that some games set the language automatically, according to the console's language, in the settings.
But I also know that some games simply don't have the content in english.

What about DD:DA?
If I buy it here? Can I get english speech AND subtitles?

Comment: From what I've read, the voices are set in English; there's an option to change the settings. But for clarification reasons, I'll try to find some solid evidence to back that up with. This link might be useful for future reference - it states that DD:DA includes full english support: http://www.gaijingamers.com/showthread.php?t=2459

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But that's only for Japanese releases. So yeah, still the doubt remains.

Comment: I'll see if I can obtain some solid evidence for you when time allows.

Comment: Thanks. Also, maybe you know this: Can I continue my saved game that was created on a UK version, in this German version?
What about the German version, has it some kind of limitation? Like censured parts or something?
I find this really hard to find on the internet.

Comment: Without testing, I wouldn't know. But making an assumption, I would guess not. I would assume that being the German version, it would be region locked. Meaning that it cannot be accessed elsewhere. 
Although, I'm not 100% certain, there's no saying that my guess is correct. I'd continue to search for information, perhaps ask on the official forums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can certainly say: yes, it has English language and English subtitles.
Altough the cover states only German subtitles, it has English subtitles, and I would say it also has those typical/standart European language subtitles.
About the saved game: I can continue the game with my previously started saved game in a UK disc with NO problems at all.

I just wish this kind of information was more transparent and easy to get.